# Reverting to old functions.php file still generates same parse error

Tags: php, wordpress

Within `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php`, I added some PHP in an attempt to create my own shortcode. When I clicked save:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'post' (T_STRING) in .../wp-content/themes/phenomenon/functions.php on line 21

Indeed, this same error appeared if I tried to go even to the main page of my site. Having no way to go back into the editor and remove the newly added code, I uploaded a backup copy of functions.php via FTP. My site started loading again. Yet when I went into `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php`, this error still appeared, even though functions.php doesn't have 21 lines of code.

Here is the current / original functions.php:

```
<?php ?><?php 

require_once (TEMPLATEPATH."/scripts/theme-js.php");
include (TEMPLATEPATH."/scripts/custom-scripts.php");
include (TEMPLATEPATH."/scripts/breadcrumbs.php");
include (TEMPLATEPATH."/scripts/write-panels.php");

include (TEMPLATEPATH."/bluzpanel/theme_options.php");
include (TEMPLATEPATH."/includes/shortcodes.php");
include (TEMPLATEPATH."/includes/wp-pagenavi.php");
include (TEMPLATEPATH."/includes/custom-widgets.php");
include (TEMPLATEPATH."/includes/register-sidebars.php");

?>
```

EDIT: I have verified that I can still use `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php` when I test it on another computer. Therefore the problem might be unique to my main computer, where I made the changes to `function.php`.

Comment: There are multiple `functions.php` files, hard to say without the full path, but you probably have an extra single or double quote somewhere in the file you modified. You also shouldn't modify the core files - anything that isn't under `wp-content`. If you upgrade WordPress (or a plugin if you modify a file there) your changes will be overwritten. Use the Action and Filter hooks to extend the functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I added in more of the path of functions.php, as you can see. (Perhaps it is silly of me to think there is something private about it.) Also I added an edit at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magically, `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php` started working again. It might have been related to my browser somehow caching the the page with the error message, though I believe tried another browser on the same computer and got the same error. Anyway, refreshing the page several times might be the solution.